# Create new order item per product unit in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to create a new order_item line per product unit in Magento. I mean, if someone buys two units of the same product, then I need the order to create two lines in the sales_flat_order_item table, each one with quantity '1'.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to rewrite the core to make this happen. you may also maybe create duplicates of products being "Item_1, Item_2, Item_3, ..." Then in the before save to catalog, you loop through an iterator, using the qty as counter, and replace each product with the "Item_n" product, and change the qty on the original one to 1?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ShaunOReilly, but I wanted to avoid rewriting core modules for this... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I meant rewrite, as in extending the core module, using new modules of your own, that way you do not change the core code physically.

Comment: Thanks ShaunOReilly, I see what you mean. Wouldn't it be enough with observers? (that's the point that it's not clear for me).

Comment: Using observers could work, and looping through each item, checking the quantity, and splitting them up should not be too hard. It is the GetProductItemBySku that will try and return the same product with 1 qty field in it. I am actually going to try it, and see what it does. You should maybe only need to override the AddToCart bit, and then it will work from there.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the order with sales_order_place_after, getting each item and it's quantity, deleting it from the cart and adding new items (I haven't finished yet, I hope it works...).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround to do this. It's limited and it should be corrected because I don't know if it takes into account promotions and other special rules. It explodes order items with qty > 1 and create new lines with qty = 1;

1. Create a module with an observer that checks the sales_order_place_after:

   ```
    <events>
   <sales_order_place_after>
           <observers>
               <explodeitems>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>Company_OrderObservers_Model_ExplodeOrderItem</class>
                   <method>explodeOrderItems</method>
               </explodeitems>
           </observers>
       </sales_order_place_after>
     <events>
   ```
2. The observer gets the ids/qty and deletes the current order items. Then it creates new ones with the parameters we got:

   ```
   function explodeOrderItems($observer)
   {

   $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();


   $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
   $products = array();

   foreach ( $items as $k => $item )
   {
       if ( $item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
       {
           $itemqty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
           if ( $itemqty > 1 )
           {
               for ( $i=0; $i < $itemqty; $i++ )
               {
                   $products[$i]['id'] = $item->getProductId();
                   $products[$i]['qty'] = 1;
               }
               $item->delete();
           }
       }
       else
           $item->delete();
   }

   $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
   $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();

   if ( $products )
   {
       foreach ( $products as $product )
       {
           $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product['id']);
           $price = $_product->getPrice();
           $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                       ->setStoreId($storeId)
                       ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                       ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                       ->setProductId($product['id'])
                       ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
                       ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                       ->setTotalQtyOrdered(1)
                       ->setQtyOrdered(1)
                       ->setName($_product->getName())
                       ->setSku($_product->getSku())
                       ->setPrice($price)
                       ->setBasePrice($price)
                       ->setOriginalPrice($price)
                       ->setRowTotal($price)
                       ->setBaseRowTotal($price);

           $order->addItem($orderItem);
       }
       $order->save();
   }
   ```